# Warning: Creating default object from empty value in ... /post.php

Tags: posts

Strange problem - when I want to add a new Post or Page I get the following error:

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /home/www/wp-admin/includes/post.php on line 641

And I am not able to make a new post or page, there is no content field, only a Title field. I repaired the database but nothing was found. I also optimized with "wp-optimize".

Comment: If you disable all plugins and switch to a standard theme, does the error persist?

Comment: Yes, these are the first things I try for sure. I also deleted all files except "wp-admin", too and uploaded new ones from a fresh 4.8 zip.

Comment: Did you solve it? I face the same problem now.